# Spinner in popup works on emulator but on device

Tags: android, spinner, android-popupwindow

This is a question similar to many others regarding `BadTokenException: Unable to add window - is your activity running?`

In short I have a popup that has two `Spinners`. When I click on them in the emulator everything works fine. However, when using my device I get exception:

`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@b3b2e85 is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
                                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:341)
                                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
                                                                                     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1417)
                                                                                     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1259)
                                                                                     at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:683)
                                                                                     at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:1235)
                                                                                     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:770)`.

Different threads suggests that it has to do with `bad context`. I have tried different contexts like `getActivity(),` `getBaseContext()` and `getApplicationContext()`. None of them have helped. I also test `isfinishing()`like some have suggested.

If I use `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` in the xml-file it works on my device. But if I use `dropdown` it fails.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.erikbylow.autoflash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

import com.example.erikbylow.autoflash.utils.FileHandler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    final static public String SOURCE_LANG = "source_lang";
    final static public String TARGET_LANG = "target_lang";

    MainActivityFragment mainFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainFragment = new MainActivityFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, mainFragment).commit();


    }


    private void deleteAllFiles(){
        FileHandler fHandler = new FileHandler();
        fHandler.deleteAllFiles(getApplicationContext());
    }
    private void printFiles(){
        FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler();
        ArrayList<String> fileNames = fileHandler.getFileNames(getApplicationContext());
        for (String s : fileNames){
            Log.e("Main Files", s);
        }
    }

    public void start_translation(View v){
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            mainFragment.showPopup(); // Here the popup is shown
        } else {
            System.out.println("IsFinishing!!");
        }
    }

    public void start_training(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TrainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

The MainActivity Fragment

```
package com.example.erikbylow.autoflash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.example.erikbylow.autoflash.testCode.TestCardView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;

/**
 * Created by erikbylow on 2017-12-29.
 */

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private String source_language;
    private String target_language;
    final private String SOURCE_ID = "source";
    final private String TARGET_ID = "target";

    final static public String SOURCE_LANG = "source_lang";
    final static public String TARGET_LANG = "target_lang";
    private ArrayList<String> acronyms;
    private String src;
    private String target;
    private PopupWindow mPopupWindow;
    public MainActivityFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_acitivity,container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        View customView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.select_language,null);


        mPopupWindow = getSelectPopup(customView);
        // Set acronyms
        acronyms = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_acronyms)));

        setSpinnerListeners(customView);
        setCtnButton(customView);
    }

    // Created the popup warning

    private void setSpinnerListeners(View view){
        Spinner spinner1 = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spinner spinner2 = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.array_languages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.array_languages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        if(spinner1==null || spinner2 == null){
            System.out.println("NULL ON SPINNER");
        }

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                src = acronyms.get(pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                target = acronyms.get(pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void setCtnButton(View view){
        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.start_translate_btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),TranslateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(SOURCE_LANG,src);
                intent.putExtra(TARGET_LANG,target);
                startActivity(intent);
                mPopupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    private PopupWindow getSelectPopup(View view){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        float row = 300*metrics.density;
        float cols = 200*metrics.density;

        PopupWindow tmp = new PopupWindow(
                view,(int)row,(int)cols);
        ImageButton closeButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ib_close);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPopupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return tmp;

    }

    public PopupWindow getPopupWindow(){
        return mPopupWindow;
    }

    public void showPopup(){
        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(getView(), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }


}
```

MainFragmentLayout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout_fragment"
tools:context="com.example.erikbylow.autoflash.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Translation"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="start_translation"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Training"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="start_training"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
/>
```

PopupViewLayout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ab2fc4"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/set_source"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/array_languages"
        android:prompt="@string/set_source" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/set_target"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/array_languages"
        android:prompt="@string/set_source" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/start_translate_btn"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just uninstall the app in your device and install again...check if the error persists..

Comment: Did not help unfortunately.